# Why is my tmux active pane title not changing back after sshing into a remote host?

Tags: tmux

I looked through the tmux man page in the the `STATUS LINE` section.

```
STATUS LINE
     tmux includes an optional status line which is displayed in the bottom line of each terminal.  By default, the status line is enabled (it may be disabled with the status session
     option) and contains, from left-to-right: the name of the current session in square brackets; the window list; the title of the active pane in double quotes; and the time and
     date.
```

The `"localhost"` in double quotes is the status pane title.

> the title of the active pane in double quotes;

Starting on my localhost, we can see the value in double quotes is `"localhost"`.

[image]

Then I ssh into a build host and the value changes to `"max@build"`. Except when I exit the session the value in quotes is still `"max@build"`.

[image]

- Why isn't the title changing back to localhost?
- Also, why doesn't `refresh-client` change the title back to localhost?
- How do I get the pane title to go back to localhost?

Answer (score 1):

The title in the status line was change by an escape sequence from the host "build". Just terminating the ssh connection doesn't change the title back.

Sending `"\ekTEST\e\\"` to the terminal will change the title to "TEST". That is ESC k TEST ESC backslash.

```
echo -en "\ekTEST\e\\"
```

On a practical note, this will also work

```
echo -e "\ekTEST"
```

Comment: How do you echo that out? I tried `echo  "\ekTEST\e\"` but it wasn't able to print

Comment: While I had written the backslash double, before it was not displayed correctly.

Comment: @mbigras Use `echo -e` to interpret escape sequences... Or `printf` should also work...

Comment: Can you type out the command? `echo -e "\ekTEST\e\"` isn't working for some reason about quotes I think

Comment: Added two examples.